# How to build windows server core on Windows 10 Pro?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-for-windows

I have the following basic Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:1903
CMD echo Hello World!
```

When I run the command:

`docker build -t latest .` or `docker build .`

My terminal hangs forever and it seems like nothing is being done.

However, if I run:

`docker pull mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:1903`

I can pull the image from the repository.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, or how to fix it. The `build` command doesn't seem to have a verbose option, and I need a docker container running Windows.

I'm using Docker in Windows 10 Pro and its configured to use Windows containers.

Comment: Try to remove `-t` so it will be `docker build .` Check system activity in the mean time, if you are in wrong folder  and folder is huge it will try to zip entire folder and send it to itself, so make sure you switch to home directory where only thing present is just DOCKERFILE

Comment: @GregorySuvalian I already tried both options and the terminal still hangs. I can run `docker run` and `docker pull` against that image, it's just `docker build` the command that won't work.

Comment: @GregorySuvalian turns out you were right. Though, for some reason the build command works faster in cmd than in PowerShell. You should post your comment as an answer so that I can mark this question as solved.

Comment: I was right about what? Directory where you are executing it from?

Comment: @GregorySuvalian yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check which directory do you execute your commands from. You shall be executing them from directory where `DOCKERFILE` is located and nothing else. If you execute say from root of C drive or any other location with big number of files then docker as a first step will try to zip all of them up and then send to a builder and hence delays.